# Find the range of $f(x)=x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+........+$ upto $\infty$

Tags: functions

Find the range of $f(x)=x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+........+$ upto $\infty$

Please help me out, I need to know the correct answer

Comment: Have you heard of geometric progression?

Comment: Ya, of course. Thanks for your help but I figured out the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ is defined as a real number only for $|x|<1$ and $f(x)=\frac x {1-x}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: Ya I know that but what about other values of x?

Comment: The function is not defined for $|x| \geq 1$. The domain is $(-1,1)$. And the answer is $(-\frac  1 2, \infty)$.

Comment: Thanks but may you tell me why function is not defined for |x|>=1  ? Is it just because for other values of x, the function will not converge to a specific value?

Comment: An infinite series cannot converge  unless the n-th term tends to $0$.